# Is it possible for "Jmeter", 'View Results Tree' output recording start after 5 minutes of start of first thread

Tags: javascript, multithreading, performance, jmeter, delayed-execution

I  want to record output to View Results Tree after 5 min. of start of JMeter. Delay should be there only for first thread. Is there any way I can do that?

Constant Timer delay every thread. I do not want to delay output in each thread.
Also tried on Flow Control Action.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by discarding results of any Samplers using i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following code:

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long) < 300000) {
    prev.setIgnore()
}
```

where:

- `TESTSTART.MS` is a [pre-defined JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedprops) holding the time when the test started
- `vars` - a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
- `prev` - a shorthand for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on the above and other JMeter API shorthands.

Assuming you put the JSR223 PostProcessor to your Test Plan all Samplers results during first 5 minutes of the test will be ignored, Listeners and .jtl results file will start receiving metrics after 5 minutes only.